# Bloquear arquivos em pasta asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

tenho uma pasta com nome de "app" quero bloquear acesso a todos os arquivos se o usuário não estiver logado.

tentei assim:

```
<location path="app">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

mas se eu acessar /app/algumArquivo.xyz ele acessa...

Comment: Já tentou "~/app"?

Comment: já, ainda consigo acessar o arquivo...

Comment: faz o seguinte teste: coloca esse trecho que tu colocou na pergunta acima do `<system.web>` do web.config, ou seja, no início do arquivo.

Comment: também não...rsrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta avisar o IIS que toda e qualquer requisição (incluindo de arquivos estáticos) deve ser processada por ele. Do jeito que estava antes, o IIS não aplica o recurso de `FormsAuthentication` sobre arquivos estáticos.

Coloque no seu arquivo `Web.config` o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: funcionou =D só removi     <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
     
    </modules> de dentro, e deu boa, não tem problema né

Comment: @Rod Isso aí. Na verdade você habilitou corretamente o `FormsAuthentication`. Deve funcionar Ok.